# Unable to change pricing tier for API Management currently in Consumption tier

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

The page on scaling an API Management service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/upgrade-and-scale) indicates there should be a "pricing tier" blade under "deployment + infrastructure"  (along with several others), but my service only has "external cache" and "custom domains".  Clicking the "pricing tier" link from the overview page does nothing.  Where do I change the pricing tier?

Note: this is an ARM-template-created consumption-tier service created about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Another note: I created several consumption tier APIM instances in different regions via the portal UI with the same behavior - you don't appear to be able to change back and forth between consumption and anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response to [this issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/42937) indicates that you can't change pricing tier on a Consumption instance. I can't find any documentation mentioning this but I would imagine that Consumption instances are provisioned on different physical hardware that can't simply be changed without re-provisioning.

Comment: Also, I now realize it says this under "Availability" in the "Upgrade and Scale" screen:  "This feature is available in the Premium, Standard, Basic, and Developer tiers of API Management."

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change tier if API management was deployed in consumption model.

To verify that check ARM template SKU default value.

```
    "sku": {
      "type": "string",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Developer",
        "Basic",
        "Standard",
        "Premium",
        "Consumption"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Consumption",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The pricing tier of this API Management service"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to do it, but you can work around the issue using `Template Spec`. Here's the overview of how you can achieve this:

- Export your APIM instance template
- Modify the template to create a consumption instance
- Add subscription keys to the template if you don't want them to change
- Delete old instance
- Create a new instance from the template with the same name

Detailed instructions:

Go to your APIM instance and find `Export template` under `Automation`

[image: Export template]

Navigate to `Template specs`

[image: Template specs]

Find the template spec you've just created and edit the version

[image]

Change SKU name to `Basic` (or other) and `capacity` to `1`

[image: Change SKU]

Remove `enableClientCertificate` property (not supported in basic SKU)

[image: Remove enableClientCertificate]

Remove `master` (built-in all-access) subscription (it will be added automatically)

[image: remove master subscription]

Find your subscriptions and add `primaryKey` and `secondaryKey` properties

[image: Set keys]

Save the `Template spec` and deploy it

[image: Deploy]